# how to get value from response in fcm push notification in php

Tags: php, push-notification

```
{
    "multicast_id":8453676721258445896,
    "success":0,
    "failure":1,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[{
        "error":"InvalidRegistration"
    }]
}
```

How can i get only success and failure value in one variable in php

Comment: both value in one variable? Why?

Comment: no in separate variable .

Comment: $success And $failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res ='{"multicast_id":8453676721258445896,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}';
$json_array=json_decode($res,true);

$success = $json_array["success"];
$failure = $json_array["failure"];
echo $success;
echo $failure;
```